# Getters/setters when first word has second letter capitalized

Tags: java, naming-conventions, getter-setter, camelcasing

What should we expect from the following name? : `mGage Program`

if I camelCase this it will be `mGageProgram` and if I generate (in eclipse) the getters and setters I will get the following:

```
public String getmGageProgram() {
    return mGageProgram;
}

public void setmGageProgram(String mGageProgram) {
    this.mGageProgram = mGageProgram;
}
```

Which to me doesn't seem right as I was expecting the `getMGageProgram()` and `setMGageProgram(value)`.

Are these getters/setters names alright?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**According to** `8.8: Capitalization of inferred names of the JavaBeans API specification`
the names generated from the IDE **are correct**.

Answer (score 3):

they are 100% correct :) but conventions differ among programmers , for me its method names in camel casing not variables. as for syntax its correct :)

Comment: Thanks. I was more concerned on serialization/deserialization object mappers than just a simple convention. It seems to work with Jackson and SpringMVC though.

Answer (score 1):

I’d like to provide just a little more depth on what the spec says. It specifies how we get from the name of a getter and/or a setter to a property name. The interesting quote in this context is:

> … to support the occasional use of all upper-case names, we check if
>   the first two characters of the name are both upper case and if so
>   leave it alone.

It’s from section *8.8: Capitalization of inferred names.*

One example given is that `URL` (as in `getURL` or `setURL`)  becomes (or stays) `URL` (not `uRL`).

So the method names that you and I would have expected, `getMGageProgram` and `setMGageProgram`, would have implied a property named `MGageProgram` with an upper case `M`. Since we wanted `mGageProgram` we need to use lower case `m` in the names of the getter and the setter.

The rules as I read them thus really allow you to use a lowercase letter right after `get` or `set` in *any* getter or setter name. This came as a peculiar surprise to me. Of course it’s not an option that we want to exploit in cases where we don’t have to.

**Link:** [JavaBeans Spec download page](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/spec-136004.html)